# Check balance amount using AT Command

Tags: modem, sim-card

Is it possible to check balance amount of my SIM card using AT Command?
Or is there any other way to do this without taking out the SIM card from GSM modem?or using PHP script..?

Thank you.

Comment: I would assume this a property of your telco operator not of your phone/sim. At least Nokia doesn't give me a hint how to do that: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/AT_Commands  If a phone can do that it depends on the make/revision of the firmware.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a SMS message via AT commands to a phone number the operator uses for reporting the balance.

For example: Vodafone.nz uses text 'BAL' on phone number 777. The operator then sends back the balance via incoming SMS message.

To send a message use AT+CMGF and AT+CMGS commands.

To read a message (containing the balance) use  AT+CMGR command.